# Warning: Location "/test/22" did not match any routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having trouble trying to make a nested route with react router.  Everything works fine when I link to the first route, but anything else nested will give me an `Warning: Location "/test/22" did not match any routes` error.

Here is snippets of my code, let me know if you need anymore information.

Router below works fine when linking to `/test` and also with `/stop`, however when trying to link `/test/22` it gives off the error.
`Main.js` below

```
class AppRouter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <Route path="stop" component={StopList}>
            <Route path=":stopid" component={Stop}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="test" component={RouteList}>
            <Route path="/22" component={StopList}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="findStops" component={FindStops}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Using the the test first link works fine.. not sure why the second test link does not work.. `findStops.js` below

```
render() {
    return (
      <section>
          <h1>test page</h1>
          <Link to="/test">test first</Link><br />
          <Link to="/test/22" >test link</Link><br/>
      </section>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone has a better answer, let me know, but I went ahead and changed this

```
<Route path="test" component={RouteList}>
   <Route path="/22" component={StopList}/>
</Route>
```

to

```
<Route path="test" component={RouteList} />
<Route path="test/22" component={StopList}/>
```

It works, but it feels like this might not be proper syntax or is incorrect style, so please correct if there's a different way.  I want to do things right the first way around. Thanks!

Comment: I had to do the same thing to make something similar work as well, I don't understand why I should have to include `test` again before `22`. Did you figure out why in the end? It's as if child routes don't really work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the slash in '/22' of the nested routed, so you should change it just to '22'. Nested routes should be assumed to be delimited by slashes.